# Would you utilise "Using" on a member which is going to be added to a list?

Tags: c#, interface

I have an `interface` and a concrete class which I am using in the code below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a DataSet read from the DB to a list of objects of a type
    /// TemplatePart. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="templatePartDataSet">DataSet containing the information.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>List of unprocessed TemplateParts.</returns>
    private static List<ITemplatePart> DataSetToTemplatePart(DataSet templatePartDataSet)
    {
        var rawTemplateParts = new List<ITemplatePart>();
        foreach (DataTable table in templatePartDataSet.Tables)
        {
            var tableName = table.ToString();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(
                    row.Field<string>(Strings.TemplateSpreadSheet_Column_PartName)))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // THE LINE RELATED TO MY QUESTION.
                var rawTemplatePart = TemplatePart.CreateTemplatePart(table, row);
                rawTemplateParts.Add(rawTemplatePart);
            }
        }
        return rawTemplateParts;
    }
```

`TemplatePart` is a simple class with 4 properties with the definition of:

```
{
    public class TemplatePart : ITemplatePart
    {
        #region Creator

        internal static TemplatePart CreateTemplatePart(DataTable table, DataRow row)
        {
            return new TemplatePart
            {
                PartName = row.Field<string>(Strings.TemplateSpreadSheet_Column_PartName),
                BasePart = row.Field<string>(Strings.TemplateSpreadSheet_Column_BasePart)
            };
        }

        #endregion // Creator

        #region Public Properties

        public string PartName { get; set; }
        public string BasePart { get; set; }
        public double? PriceDom { get; set; }
        public double? PriceInt { get; set; }

        #endregion // Public Properties
    }
}
```

and the `ITemplatePart` as:

```
namespace PriorityPriceGenerator2.Model.TemplatePart
{
    interface ITemplatePart
    {
    }
}
```

of course the interface hasn't been implemented completely. And also the concrete class doesn't have the `IDisposable` yet.

Would you prefer (/if it's necessary or even totally wrong) to do such thing in the marked line.

```
using (var rawTemplatePart = TemplatePart.CreateTemplatePart(table, row))
    rawTemplateParts.Add(rawTemplatePart);
```

And why? I want to know what happens to a member added to the list which is in the Using. Would it get destroyed and recreated in the `List`? Would it get destroyed because of using after I am done with the `List` ?

And please, 
let me know if you see any other issues.

Comment: The `using` keyword is syntactic sugar for `try { <declaration>; <body> } finally { (<declaredThing> as IDisposable).Dispose(); }`. Objects should throw an exception when used after being disposed. Therefore, I see no situation in which your example makes sense. `using` has one purpose. Using it for anything else will only confuse people.

Comment: Why do you think `using` makes sense there? What would be its purpose?

Comment: @svick I thought it wouldn't be a use for that object after I added it to the list. definitional need to get the thinking pattern right. I must have a wrong understanding of `Using` in general.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code is incomplete and not ready for review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use `using` on the object that you add to the list.

When you add the object to the list, it's just the reference to the object that gets added. There is no copy of the object created for the list.

If you use `using` on the object, it will be disposed at the end of the code block, which is a single statement in your example. Right after you have added the object to the list it will be disposed.

Although nothing happens automatically when you dispose an object, it's customary that the object should be unusable after the `Dispose` method has been called. The `IDisposable` interface is intended for controlling the lifespan of objects, usually to free unmanaged resources when you are done using the object.

After you are done using the objects in the list, you should dispose them.

However, from what I can tell there isn't going to be any unmanaged resources in your object, so there wouldn't be any need for it to implement `IDisposable`. The (supposedly) database related objects are only used during the creation of the object, and so far there are nothing unmanaged in the class.

Comment: `IDisposable` is commonly used for many different things other than freeing unmanaged resources. Joining background threads or unsubscribing from events, for example. So `there isn't going to be any unmanaged resources in your object, so there wouldn't be any need for it to implement IDisposable` is a questionable logic in my opinion. Otherwise i agree with what you've said. :)

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak: Yes, there are other possible uses, but as the documentation puts it; *"The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources."* Anyhow, if you use it for any other purpose you should be aware of that usage. :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be re-written:

```
private static IEnumerable<ITemplatePart> DataSetToTemplatePart(DataSet templatePartDataSet)
{
    foreach (DataTable table in templatePartDataSet.Tables)
    {
        var tableName = table.ToString();

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string> Strings.TemplateSpreadSheet_Column_PartName)))
            {
                continue;
            }

            yield TemplatePart.CreateTemplatePart(table, row);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the yield keyword.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx